# Which function can be used to swap matrices (Mat) in opencv4android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am working on a project in OpenCV4android. I have to Mat objects that I would like to swap, in the same way the c++ function cv::swap(Mat &a, Mat &b) swaps matrices a and b. What is the equivalent java function in  OpenCV4android?

Comment: do you want to simply swap the pointers to the data or actually exchange the individual data items between the two memory locations?

Comment: I want to swap the pointers to the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is harder to do in Java as although you can pass the Mat objects into a function that can then be used to manipulate the data they point to, the actual object addresses are passed by value so they can't be changed in a function.

There might be clever ways of doing this in a function but assuming the two Mats you want to swap are A and B then I'd recommend:

```
Mat tmp = B;
B = A;
A = tmp;
```

works inline but won't work if you try and wrap in a function.